# when would you use this structure?

Tags: modal-verb, conjugation, modal-particle

is this how you make a past tense of a modal verb and if not what is this?

ich habe ... sollen.(is it the perfect past tense(would it mean I should have))

what is the difference between man sollst and man soll and man sollte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are stumbling over the **Ersatzinfinitiv** here.

This is Perfekt:

> Ich habe eingekauft.
>
> Ich habe gesollt.

But *sollen* requires a verb to define what you should have done. In this case *auf Hochdeutsch* it's **not**

> <s>Ich habe einkaufen gesollt.</s>

but instead

> Ich habe einkaufen sollen.

Please note the **Ersatzinfinitiv** isn't used in some Southern German dialects. For these, *Ich habe einkaufen gesollt.* is correct.

Same with *müssen, können* and other verbs which require a verb to define them further. Not only modals, but e.g. also *brauchen, heißen, lassen, sehen, hören, fühlen, helfen*. For the latter, it's often hard to guess when to use the *Ersatzinfinitiv* and when not.

> Ich habe ihr einkaufen geholfen.
>
> Ich habe ihr einkaufen helfen sollen.

simple but … tricky …

---

*man soll* and *man sollte* differ in tense. The first is *Präsens*, the latter *Präteritum*. If you aren't sure about the *man*, replace it with *er*. They are both third person.

For this reason *man sollst* is ungrammatical. Because *man* is third person, while *sollst* is second person.

Comment: Are you sure about your remark about Southern German dialects not using the Ersatzinfinitiv? I live in Austria (albeit Vorarlberg, but relavites all over Austria), but never heard it in Austrian German without an Ersatzinfinitiv; at least not that I can now construct a sentence in any Austrian dialect that would sound awfully wrong without it. Can you specifiy which dialects are affected?

Comment: Not sure. I had a source for that at some point but I cannot find it.